# How to disable the onclick function of the form until validation is complete?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the [jQuery Validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

I have the following code in an onClick function of my form submit button.

```
onClick = "parent.$.fn.fancybox.close();parent.location.reload();"
```

When the form detects a field is not filled in, it successfully halts submission of the form, however the `onClick` event still fires.

Is there a way to get this event to also halt firing when this occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [submit handler function](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#Too_much_recursion) with the validation plugin instead of an onclick:

```
$("#myform").validate({
 submitHandler: function(form) {
   parent.$.fn.fancybox.close();
   parent.location.reload();
   form.submit();
 }
});
```

The submitHandler gets triggered after a successful validation of the form.